# how to zoom asset in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, viewer, forge

we have implemented the forge viewer in our web application. When clicking the asset in forge viewer, we need to make our entire page should be loaded.

any click event is available when object is selected in viewer?

please provide the function name or code, we need to hit any function when asset selecting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below even, you can write this event after you create instance of viewer

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelectionChanged);

function onSelectionChanged()
{
perform your operation;
}
```

for zooming the asset you can use

```
viewer.fitToView([arrayofdbid],viewer.model);
```

if you want to highlight selection, you can use,

```
viewer.select([array of dbid]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to add file name or URN as extra  parameter for fitToView Function?