# Zoom camera inside room and show interior of the room

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are using forge viewer in our web application. We need to zoom camera inside room and show interior of the room.

Please help me to find out that how we can view room interior in forge viewer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question on SO, here is an already answered link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65827867/5747150

Answer (score 0):

You may check out this sample. It’s a revision of my sample [forge-viewer-traveling-path](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-traveling-path). It will move the viewer camera smoothly to the center point of the room’s bounding box.

Demo: https://youtu.be/3MzihDJpi70

Here is the main extension: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-traveling-path/blob/room-navigation/public/js/MoveToRoomExt.js

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copyright (c) Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved
// Written by Forge Partner Development
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in
// object code form for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted,
// provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
// that both that copyright notice and the limited warranty and
// restricted rights notice below appear in all supporting
// documentation.
//
// AUTODESK PROVIDES THIS PROGRAM "AS IS" AND WITH ALL FAULTS.
// AUTODESK SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
// MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR USE.  AUTODESK, INC.
// DOES NOT WARRANT THAT THE OPERATION OF THE PROGRAM WILL BE
// UNINTERRUPTED OR ERROR FREE.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

(function () {
    class RoomListPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
        constructor(parent) {
            const options = {};

            //  Height adjustment for scroll container, offset to height of the title bar and footer by default.
            if (!options.heightAdjustment)
                options.heightAdjustment = 70;

            if (!options.marginTop)
                options.marginTop = 0;

            //options.addFooter = false;

            const viewer = parent.viewer;
            super(viewer.container, viewer.container.id + 'RoomListPanel', 'Rooms', options);

            this.container.classList.add('adn-docking-panel');
            this.container.classList.add('adn-room-list-panel');
            this.createScrollContainer(options);

            this.viewer = viewer;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.options = options;
            this.uiCreated = false;

            this.addVisibilityListener(async (show) => {
                if (!show) return;

                if (!this.uiCreated)
                    await this.createUI();
            });
        }

        async createUI() {
            this.uiCreated = true;

            const div = document.createElement('div');

            const treeDiv = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(treeDiv);
            this.treeContainer = treeDiv;
            this.scrollContainer.appendChild(div);

            const data = await this.getRoomData();
            this.buildTree(data);
        }

        async getRoomData() {
            const getRoomDbIds = () => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.viewer.search(
                        'Revit Rooms',
                        (dbIds) => resolve(dbIds),
                        (error) => reject(error),
                        ['Category'],
                        { searchHidden: true }
                    );
                });
            };

            const getPropertiesAsync = (dbId) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.viewer.getProperties(
                        dbId,
                        (result) => resolve(result),
                        (error) => reject(error),
                    );
                });
            }

            const data = [];

            try {
                const roomDbIds = await getRoomDbIds();
                if (!roomDbIds || roomDbIds.length <= 0) {
                    throw new Error('No Rooms found in current model');
                }

                for (let i = 0; i < roomDbIds.length; i++) {
                    const dbId = roomDbIds[i];
                    const propData = await getPropertiesAsync(dbId);

                    data.push({
                        id: propData.externalId,
                        dbId,
                        name: propData.name
                    });
                }

            } catch (ex) {
                console.warn(`[RoomListPanel]: ${ex}`);
                throw new Error('Failed to extract room data');
            }

            return data;
        }

        getBoundingBox(dbId) {
            const model = this.viewer.model;
            const it = model.getInstanceTree();
            const fragList = model.getFragmentList();
            let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

            it.enumNodeFragments(dbId, (fragId) => {
                let box = new THREE.Box3();
                fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, box);
                bounds.union(box);
            }, true);

            return bounds;
        }

        buildTree(data) {
            const nodes = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                const node = {
                    id: data[i].id,
                    dbId: data[i].dbId,
                    type: 'spaces',
                    text: data[i].name
                };

                nodes.push(node);
            }

            console.log(nodes);

            $(this.treeContainer)
                .jstree({
                    core: {
                        data: nodes,
                        multiple: false,
                        themes: {
                            icons: false,
                            name: 'default-dark'
                        }
                    },
                    sort: function (a, b) {
                        const a1 = this.get_node(a);
                        const b1 = this.get_node(b);
                        return (a1.text > b1.text) ? 1 : -1;
                    },
                    checkbox: {
                        keep_selected_style: false,
                        three_state: false,
                        deselect_all: true,
                        cascade: 'none'
                    },
                    types: {
                        spaces: {}
                    },
                    plugins: ['types', 'sort', 'wholerow'],
                })
                .on('changed.jstree', async (e, data) => {
                    console.log(e, data);
                    console.log(data.node.original);

                    const { dbId } = data.node.original;

                    if (!dbId) return;

                    const bbox = this.getBoundingBox(dbId);
                    const center = bbox.center();
                    const point = new THREE.Vector3(center.x, center.y, bbox.min.z);

                    this.parent.tweenToPoint(point);
                });
        }
    }

    class MoveToRoomExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
        constructor(viewer, options) {
            super(viewer, options);
            this.cameraTweenTool = null;
            this.uiCreated = false;
        }

        onToolbarCreated(toolbar) {
            const panel = new RoomListPanel(this);
            viewer.addPanel(panel);

            this.panel = panel;

            const roomsPanelButton = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('room-panel-button');
            roomsPanelButton.onClick = () => {
                panel.setVisible(!panel.isVisible());
            };

            roomsPanelButton.setToolTip('Open room list panel');

            this.group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('room-nav-tool-group');
            this.group.addControl(roomsPanelButton);
            toolbar.addControl(this.group);
        }

        tweenToPoint(point) {
            this.viewer.setActiveNavigationTool('bimwalk');

            const views = [];
            const up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            const currentEye = this.viewer.navigation.getPosition().clone();

            const targetPos = point.clone().add(up.clone().multiplyScalar(1.7 * 3.2808399));
            const sightDir = point.clone().sub(currentEye).normalize();
            const eyeLen = this.viewer.navigation.getEyeVector().length();
            const target = targetPos.clone().add(sightDir.clone().multiplyScalar(eyeLen));

            views.push({
                up: up.toArray(),
                eye: targetPos.toArray(),
                target: target.toArray()
            });

            this.processTweens(views);
        }

        executeTweenPromised(view) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const onTweenExecuted = (event) => {
                    console.log(event);
                    this.viewer.removeEventListener(
                        Autodesk.ADN.CameraTweenTool.CAMERA_TWEEN_ANIMATION_COMPLETED_EVENT,
                        onTweenExecuted
                    );

                    resolve();
                };

                this.viewer.addEventListener(
                    Autodesk.ADN.CameraTweenTool.CAMERA_TWEEN_ANIMATION_COMPLETED_EVENT,
                    onTweenExecuted
                );

                this.cameraTweenTool.tweenCameraTo({ viewport: view });
            });
        }

        processTweens(data) {
            //process each promise
            //refer to http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h3zaw8u8/
            const promisesInSequence = (tasks, callback) => {
                const results = [];
                return tasks.reduce((p, item) => {
                    return p.then(() => {
                        return callback(item).then((data) => {
                            results.push(data);
                            return results;
                        });
                    });
                }, Promise.resolve());
            };

            //start to process
            return promisesInSequence(data, (d) => this.executeTweenPromised(d));
        }

        async load() {
            const loadCSS = (href) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                const el = document.createElement('link');
                el.rel = 'stylesheet';
                el.href = href;
                el.onload = resolve;
                el.onerror = reject;
                document.head.appendChild(el);
            });

            await Promise.all([
                Autodesk.Viewing.Private.theResourceLoader.loadScript('https://unpkg.com/@tweenjs/tween.js@18.6.4/dist/tween.umd.js', 'TWEEN'),
                Autodesk.Viewing.Private.theResourceLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', '$'),
                Autodesk.Viewing.Private.theResourceLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/jstree.min.js', '$'),
                loadCSS('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/themes/default/style.min.css'),
                loadCSS('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/themes/default-dark/style.min.css'),
                this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.BimWalk'),
                this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ADN.CameraTweenTool')
            ]);

            this.viewer.setBimWalkToolPopup(false);
            this.cameraTweenTool = this.viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ADN.CameraTweenTool');

            console.log('MoveToRoomExtension has been loaded.');
            return true;
        }

        async unload() {
            this.viewer.unloadExtension('Autodesk.ADN.CameraTweenTool');
            this.viewer.setBimWalkToolPopup(true);

            delete this.cameraTweenTool;
            this.cameraTweenTool = null;

            console.log('MoveToRoomExtension has been unloaded.');
            return true;
        }
    }

    Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('Autodesk.ADN.MoveToRoomExtension', MoveToRoomExtension);
})();
```